# in Bootstrap 4, multiple item slider (3 items shows at the same time on desktop screen), make them one by one when it comes to mobile size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

in Bootstrap 4, multiple item slider (3 items shows at the same time on desktop screen), I want to show  sliders one by one when it comes to mobile size, but it shows three together vertically.

in desktop screen it shows like the following:
[image]

but on mobile screen it shows like the following:

[image]

The problem is, I want to show the sliders  one by one, when it shows on mobile and ipad screen.

you can try the code on w3school [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel).

there is code for this problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="col-12 responsive" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="col-12 responsive" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="col-12 responsive" >
      </div>
    </div>
     </div>

      <div class="carousel-item ">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="col-12 responsive" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="col-12 responsive" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="col-12 responsive" >
      </div>
    </div>
     </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="col-12 responsive" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="col-12 responsive" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="col-12 responsive" >
      </div>
    </div>
     </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#carouselExample').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

  
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 3;
    var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;
    
    if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction=="left") {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
            else {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
        }
    }
});





  $(document).ready(function() {
/* show lightbox when clicking a thumbnail */
    $('a.thumb').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var content = $('.modal-body');
      content.empty();
        var title = $(this).attr("title");
        $('.modal-title').html(title);        
        content.html($(this).html());
        $(".modal-profile").modal({show:true});
    });

  });
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    /* show 3 items */
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-inner .active,
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }

    .carouselPrograms .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }

    .carouselPrograms .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    .carouselPrograms .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -33.333%;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    /* left or forward direction */
    .carouselPrograms .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }

    /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0%;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    /* right or prev direction */
    .carouselPrograms .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carouselPrograms .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->




<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="carouselExample" class="carouselPrograms carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4  active">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 1" class="thumb">
                      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=1" alt="slide 1">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 ">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 3" class="thumb">
                     <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=2" alt="slide 2">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 ">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 4" class="thumb">
                     <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=3" alt="slide 3">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 ">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 5" class="thumb">
                     <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=4" alt="slide 4">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 ">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 6" class="thumb">
                      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=5" alt="slide 5">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 ">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 7" class="thumb">
                      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=6" alt="slide 6">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 ">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 8" class="thumb">
                      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=7" alt="slide 7">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="carousel-item col-md-4  ">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" title="image 2" class="thumb">
                     <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=8" alt="slide 8">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, it is very good example, even it still has error